# BluetoothChat doesn't work

Tags: android, bluetooth

I can't connect Motorola Droid and Nexus One using BluetoothChat It's always return "Unnable to connect". So the socket is always close.

But when I try to connect Motorola Droid and Nokia N97 They are always connect.

How can I connect Motorola Droid and Nexus One ? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this [article](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/android/thread?tid=017d25526ece249f&hl=en), since there seems to be a few features on Nexus One Bluetooth.